# Yii2 Pjax inside ListView not working

Tags: yii2, pjax

I have been trying to resolve this issue in these few days, basically i am trying to have commetn and child comments, the comment has a button/link called 'retrievecomment' to retrieve child comment.

I found out that The pjax is not working, it keeps refreshing the whole page.

**Edited: The code below is inside _list_comment.php, _list_comment.php is inside the index.php ListView, So _list_comment.php will be called several times depends on the number of items**

```
    <div class="row">   
            <?= $model['comment']?>
    </div>


    <?php Pjax::begin([
            'id' => 'childCommentData-'.$comment_id,
            'timeout' => 5000,
            'clientOptions'=>[
                    'container' => '#childCommentData-' . $comment_id,

                    'linkSelector'=>'#retrieveComment'.$comment_id
                    ]
            ]);?>
            <div  class="row">

                <div id="selector"align="right">
                <?= Html::a('Retrieve Comment', ["../../thread/index?id=" . $model['thread_id'] . "&comment_id=" . $comment_id], 
                                            ['data-pjax' => '#childCommentData-'.$comment_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-default'
                                            ,'id' => 'retrieveComment' . $comment_id]) ?>
                </div>
                <div  class="col-md-12">

                    <?php if(isset($retrieveChildData)){ ?>
                        <?= ListView::widget([

                                'dataProvider' => $retrieveChildData,
                                'options' => [
                                    'tag' => 'div',
                                    'class' => 'list-wrapper',
                                        'id' => 'list-wrapper',
                                ],
                                    'layout' => "\n{items}\n{pager}",

                                'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                                    return $this->render('_list_child_comment',['model' => $model]);
                                }, 
                                'pager' => [
                                    'firstPageLabel' => 'first',
                                    'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
                                    'nextPageLabel' => 'next',
                                    'prevPageLabel' => 'previous',
                                    'maxButtonCount' => 3,
                                ],
                            ]) ?>

                    <?php } ?>


                </div>
        </div>
        <?php Pjax::end();?>

</div>
```

The error  says "Model is not defined" which is the outer space of the pjax. This is the reason why i think the whole page is refreshed

**I also put this in the java script code**

```
           <?php  $this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/js/list_comment.js');
        $script =<<< JS
    $(document).pjax('retrieveComment' + $comment_id, '#childCommentData-' + $comment_id, { fragment: '#childCommentData-' + $comment_id });

    $('#childCommentData-' + $comment_id ).on('pjax:error', function (event) {
                                alert('Failed to load the page');
                                event.preventDefault();
                            });
    JS;
        $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
```

And i keep receive the alert failed to load page.

**The response header:** 
Request URL:http://localhost/startUp/thread/index?id=1&comment_id=1&_pjax=%23childCommentData-1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Response Headers
view source
Connection:close
Content-Length:1387
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 29 Dec 2015 12:02:18 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.12
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/startUp/thread/index?id=1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:UkwwSXdGUE4gO2MdRCMBDDENRBMkMykHGQ9XeB4uYTlnHGECGgkbPQ==
X-PJAX:true
X-PJAX-Container:#childCommentData-1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
id:1
comment_id:1
_pjax:#childCommentData-1

Answer (score 0):

this is bad:

```
<?= Html::a('Retrieve Comment', ["../../thread/index?id=" . 
     $model['thread_id']. "&comment_id=" . $comment_id], 
     ['data-pjax' => '#childCommentData-'.$comment_id, 'class' => 'btn btn default','id' => 'retrieveComment' . $comment_id]) 
?>
```

the way is:

```
<?php
    $url = Html::a('Retrieve Comment', ["/module/controller/index",[
        "id"=> $model['thread_id'], 
        "comment" => $model["comment"]
    ]); 
    echo $url;
?>
```

In your controller/action you can add pjax header to generate url:

```
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('X-PJAX-URL', Url::toRoute(["/module/controller/action", "id" => $model->id , 'comment'=> $comment->id]) );
```

I wrote one behaivor to yii for generate automatic this header X-PAJAX-URL:
https://github.com/yiiforces/yii2-pjax-url-behavior

for used in your /controller/action only add this in your controller behaivors

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'pjax-url' => [
            'class'   => 'yiiforces\pjaxUrlBehaivor\PjaxUrlBehaivor',
            'actions' => ['index'],
            'extraParams' => ['extra', 'lorem ipsum'] // incluse you can add more params to url
        ],
    ];
}
```